# MariaDb Slow Query log - only query time is high

Tags: mariadb, mysql-slow-query-log, tokudb

I have the following entry in my slow query log:

```
Query_time: 4.000347 
Lock_time: 0.000095 
Rows_sent: 0 
Rows_examined: 0

update `my_table` set `a` = null, `b` = 'x', c= ... (updating around 20 fields) where `id` = 1234;
```

`id` is the primary key in this table; and there is a record which matches this `id`

A select by PK is fast. And in most cases update by PK runs a lot faster; so I'm trying to work out the cause of the slower ones.

No significant spikes show up on CPU, I/O or memory monitoring; and the load on the system is relatively flat.

There seems to be some pattern with how close to exactly 4 seconds these queries are. Its not like I have a distribution between 2 and 6 seconds; they all right on 4!

The 4 second PK updates show up in little groups; and some of them came 4 seconds; 1 after the other.

All that; seems to indicate something ... odd.

[image]

There are over 1000 db connections on the server, so I'm wondering if there could be some thread scheduling stuff clogging things up from time to time?

Comment: Which Engine?..

Comment: Ah; very relevant point - the table is in TokuDB

Comment: Yes, very relevant.  I added a tag.  And I don't know enough about TokuDB to give any further insight.  How fast is `SELECT * FROM my_table where id = 1234`?

Comment: Updated the question with the extra details. A select by PK is fast. And in most cases update by PK runs a lot faster.

Comment: `id` is not  the PK?  Please add `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to your Question.  (That would have provided the engine.)